# Should I resize photos before or after image optimization?

Tags: file-format, image-compression, rescaling, file-size

I am a software dev who appreciates stunning imagry in sites I build, but am also very conscious of page size. My workflow has me adjusting image sizes to the maximum resolution they will be displayed to the user. I also use [ImageOptim](https://imageoptim.com/mac) a tool that applies a few compression methods to my images. I am wondering what is better though, to compress the images before I resize them, or after?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "ImageOptim" tool pulls together a bunch of other things, and in the case of JPEG files, the relevant thing is the [MozJPEG optimizing encoder](https://github.com/mozilla/mozjpeg). If you use this encoder and then resize and save with a *different* encoder, you will lose the benefit. Saving with the optimizer needs to be the last step.

Also worth noting: if you're starting with a JPEG and then saving as JPEG using a non-optimizing encoder and then saving *again* with MozJPEG, you are probably introducing artifacts. Those won't just reduce image quality — they may actually make the final image size *worse*. So, use a lossless format like TIFF or PNG as your intermediate. (PNG will lose metadata, but since you're throwing that away to get the smallest possible images *anyway*, that's fine.)